# To add a webPage inside the Form in Html?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I Designed a form by using html for PhoneGap Application,In that form i added  Buttons and labels,and inside the labels and Button i want to add webpage.  how to Display the webpage in center?

Comment: Am I drunk or does this question make no sense?

Comment: In Form ,i added a label at top and buttons at bottom,in between(center) i want to added a webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
<form>
<iframe src="someotherpage.html" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
</form>
```

?

will not have any content of the iframe available to the form as elements

```
<form></form>
<iframe src="someotherpage.html"></iframe>
<form></form>
```

or

```
<form>
<div></div>
</form>
```

where you ajax in a page from your own domain into the div

Comment: <form>
<iframe src="someotherpage.html"></iframe>
</form>
This code is Working Fine Sir,Thank You..Is it possible to Change the Height and Width of source?

Comment: This code is working fine in browser Sir,But in emulator (Galaxy Tab)can not change the width and height of source. Please tell me some solution.Thanks in advance

Comment: try `<style>iframe { width:300px; height:400px }</style>`